Local extreme points of $f(x)=\frac{5}{4} x^{\frac{4}{5}} - |x-2|$
Consider the real function $f(x)=\frac{5}{4} x^{\frac{4}{5}} - |x-2|$.
$f$ is a continuous function and it is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ except at $\{0,2\}$.
Indeed, $f$ is as follows:
(i) If $x \geq 2$, then $f(x)=\frac{5}{4} x^{\frac{4}{5}}-x+2$.
(ii) If $x < 2$, then $f(x)=\frac{5}{4} x^{\frac{4}{5}}+x-2$.
Hence,
(i) If $x > 2$, then $f'(x)= x^{-\frac{1}{5}}-1$.
(ii) If $x < 2$, then $f'(x)= x^{-\frac{1}{5}}+1$. Here we must exclude $x=0$ where $f'$ is not defined.
(iii) If $x=2$, then $f'$ does not exist (the one-sided limits of $f'$ are different).
Solving $f'=0$ we obtain $x=-1$.
Therefore, we have three critical points $\{-1,0,2\}$.
By checking the sign of the derivative $f'$, we see that $x=-1$ is maximum, $x=0$ is minimum and $x=2$ is maximum.

My question is: Why in Wolframalpha the graph of $f$ looks different from what I have found? Only $x=2$ looks like a maximum point. $\{-1,0\}$ do not look like extreme points.


Thank you very much!

When $x<0$, WolframAlpha is using the complex exponential to evaluate the expression $x^{4/5}$, that is why in your image there is an orange graph which represents the imaginary part.
To get the desired result, you should use the alternative definition of exponentiation, that is, $x^{4/5}=e^{(4/5)\ln(|x|)}$ (which is valid because the numerator is even).
Rewriting $f(x)=\dfrac{5}{4}e^{4/5\ln(|x|)}-|x-2|$ one gets the desired result.

Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful! What happens in wolframalpha when the numerator is odd? For example, $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is plotted only for $x>0$.

If the numerator is odd and the numerator is even you are taking an even root of a negative number, which is not a real number; if both are odd as in your case, it plots the root, for $x^{1/3}$ it would graph the cube root.

I guess you meant "denominator is even", ok, I meant only for odd denominators. Thank you!

Functions with a fractional exponent are, in general, not defined for negative bases. Most probably, WolframAlpha is programmed in such a way that, whenever it sees a fractional exponent it only plots the result for $x>0$ (or it uses the complex form of the exponential/logarithm). In order to make it show what we want, we need to express the power in its exponential form.
